# How to perform a linear fit of a path in the plane?

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, linear-regression

I have an ordered set of $n$ points $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$ and I would like to choose an ordered subset of these points, say $(x_{k_1},y_{k_1}),\dots,(x_{k_s},y_{k_s})$, with $(x_{k_1},y_{k_1})=(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_{k_s},y_{k_s})=(x_n,y_n)$ and such that they "best" fit the whole path.

How can I perform this?

Comment: a) what kind of interpolation are you going to use (polynomial, spline, ...) ? b)please define what exactly you mean by "best fit the whole path".

Comment: I would like to use a piecewise linear fit

Comment: That's ok, but then what is "best" ? I suppose a combination of less pieces and least error. But how to weight each of them ??

Comment: Ok, say a good fit. Not necessarily the best in some sense. I thought to fix a tolerance treshold and ask that if three consecutive points lay on the same line then the second and the third one have to be neglected.

Comment: If the set of points you have is finite, then isn't the path already piecewise linear?

Comment: Yes, but i would like to have only few points. If I have 100 points which are (almost) collinear I can choose only the first and the last one and have almost the same path.

Comment: @aleio1: So, what you are really asking is how to do 2D polygonal curve simplification?

Comment: It could be what I am looking for. Could you give me some reference? My strategy (some comment above) is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make up a table of the [divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) up to the second degree, and discard the points that have a "low" 2nd div.difference with the points nearby.
The segments connecting the points remaining will pass "quite near" to the discarded ones.